# TeratermからサーバにSSH接続できない

Tags: ssh, teraterm

Teratermからサーバに接続ができません。

二つのIPアドレスを所持していて、一つは問題ありません。
新しく作成したほうがなぜか入れません。
まったく同じ手順でIPアドレスの箇所だけ変えています。

「ユーザ名」と「秘密鍵」でログインしています。

ログには`Did not receive identification string from～`とありました。
もともと所持していたものでは上記の秘密鍵だけで通るのですが、新しいものは秘密鍵を打ち込んでいるのに、パスフレーズを入力するように促してきます。

SSH2を選択していますが通りません。どう設定を変えれば改善されるでしょうか？

追記
・知識不足で申し訳ないのですが、`ssh -vvv`コマンドが作動せず。調べたのですが接続ログが表示される他のコマンドに行きつけなかったので確認できていません。他に方法あればご教授ください。
また、接続できないほうの接続ログは、接続できない状態で確認は可能なのでしょうか。
・sshd_config確認できました。以下です。確認はしましたが万が一個人情報なるものがありましたら削除しますのでご教授ください。

```conf
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.93 2014/■■～～ ～～ djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
# SELinux about this change.
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
#
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

# The default requires explicit activation of protocol 1
#Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024
```

・OpenSSHか他のものかという判断は何でするでしょうか？
・初歩的で申し訳ありませんが更新はどうやるのでしょうか？調べたところ更新が見つけられず、一度アンインストールして再度最新バージョンを入れなおす方法しか見つけられませんでした。作業用のディレクトリやらタスクのクローンやら色々データ入れているので、なるべくアンインストールはせずアップデートしたいです。
・更新について
[image: 更新]ここからは更新できないのでしょうか？公式HPから最新のものをDLするとすると既存のもとの、新しいものと二つ存在してしまうことになるのでしょうか？

Comment: 2つのIPのサーバーの、/etc/ssh/sshd_config の中身を比較すると違いはありますか？

Comment: 各サーバへのssh時に `ssh -vvv` で詳細な接続ログを表示し、その内容を質問に追記してみてもらえますか？

Comment: Teraterm側の問題に感じますね。秘密鍵はOpenSSH形式ですか？

Comment: TeraTermはWindowsのアプリで更新は上書きするだけだと思うのですが難しいでしょうか。万一更新が出来ない場合でも、いま使ってるバージョンを確認して追記してみてください。 / `ssh -vvv`はLinux環境で実行するコマンドなので、TereTermでは実行できません。sshではログインできないサーバも代わりの方法でログイン出来ているなら、`ssh -vvv localhost`や、もう一方のログイン出来ているサーバからssh接続を試すなどいくつか別の手段が考えられますよね。

Answer (score 2):

[[SSH] Did not receive identification string from を解決するの巻](https://blog.trippyboy.com/2012/centos/ssh-did-not-receive-identification-string-from-%E3%82%92%E8%A7%A3%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E5%B7%BB/)　という記事に、sshdが許可しているプロトコルのバージョンと、SSHクライアントが使っているプロトコルのバージョンの間に齟齬が生じている場合の解決方法が説明されています。

プロトコルのバージョン違いは、Did not receive identification string fromというログ記録の原因の一つなので、記事を参考にして確認されてはいかがでしょうか。